# How do we unit test a Model Mixin with ember-cli

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have few `Ember.Mixin` in my app that contains `DS.attr()` and / or `DS.belongsTo()`. I was wondering how should I unit test them ?

By default, ember-cli generate this test

```js
test('it works', function(assert) {
  var MyModelObject = Ember.Object.extend(MyModelMixin);
  var subject = MyModelObject.create();
  assert.ok(subject);
});
```

But when I tried to interact with an `DS.attr()` I got the following error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property '_attributes' of undefined
  at hasValue (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:90650:25)
  at Class.get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:90730:13)
  at Descriptor.ComputedPropertyPrototype.get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:29706:28)
  at Object.get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:35358:19)
  at Class.get (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:49734:38)
  at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/assets/tests.js:20126:25)
  at runTest (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:2779:28)
  at Object.run (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:2764:4)
  at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:2906:11
  at process (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:2565:24)
```

Which make senses. What is the best way to do it ? Should I create a `DS.Model` within the test and then apply the mixin on it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Unit testing a model mixin like this is a little tricky since it needs access to the store in order to create the model.  Usually, the store is not available in mixin tests because there isn't even a container.  Additionally, since we just want to test the mixin, we don't want to require a *real* model, so we can create and register a phony host model just for the tests.  Here's how I did this.

First, pull in 'ember-data' and use the helpers from 'ember-qunit' instead of the stock helpers from 'qunit'.  Replace this:

```
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
```

With this:

```
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import DS from 'ember-data';
```

Then, you update your module declaration like this:

```
moduleFor('mixin:my-model-mixin', 'Unit | Mixin | my model mixin', {
  // Everything in this object is available via `this` for every test.
  subject() {
    // The scope here is the module, so we have access to the registration stuff.
    // Define and register our phony host model.
    let MyModelMixinObject = DS.Model.extend(MyModelMixin);
    this.register('model:my-model-mixin-object', MyModelMixinObject);

    // Once our model is registered, we create it via the store in the
    // usual way and return it. Since createRecord is async, we need
    // an Ember.run.
    return Ember.run(() => {
      let store = Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('service:store');
      return store.createRecord('my-model-mixin-object', {});
    });
  }
});
```

Once you have this setup in place, you can then use `this.subject()` in individual tests to get an object for testing.

```
test('it exists', function(assert) {
  var subject = this.subject();
  assert.ok(subject);
});
```

At this point, it's just a standard unit test.  You may need to wrap async or computed code in an Ember.run block:

```
test('it doubles the value', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);
  var subject = this.subject();
  Ember.run(() => {
    subject.set('someValue', 20);
    assert.equal(subject.get('twiceSomeValue'), 40);
  });
});
```